# Combine Singles and generate a data class Single

Tags: kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2, rx-kotlin, rx-kotlin2

I have a question around Single and haven't been able to find a good answer for that yet.
I have to return a Single from a method where I get 2 Single sources. The problem is I need to use the output of the 2 singles to modify a class and then send it back. Ideally, it should be something like `Observable.combineLatest` but I haven't found a good answer yet.

```
data class A (val resultX : Int, val resultY: Int)
```

I have 2 sources of Single that fills up the A object.

```
fun resultX() : Single<Int>
fun resultY() : Single<Int>
```

What I want to do is combine the results of the above 2 `Single` and send back a result `A` object.

```
Single.<blah>(resultX(), resultY()) { resultX, resultY -> A(resultX, resultY)}
```

Is there a method that could help me combine these? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it in two ways:

```
Single.zip(resultX(), resultY()) { resultX, resultY -> A(resultX, resultY) }
```

or

```
resultX().zipWith(resultY()) { resultX, resultY -> A(resultX, resultY) }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Single.zip did the trick.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).